# Setting Global Variables for Mysql On Ubuntu 17

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set some global variables and set session for a subscriber mailer software to work correctly. But when I try to set those variables in `my.cnf` file and restart the `mysql` server, I get this error,

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Below is `my.cnf` file

```
# Copyright (c) 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301 USA

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

mysql> SET SESSION sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it looks like you've got some copy-paste issues going on. The `mysql>` is the prompt from the console client, so this should never be in any configuration file.

Secondly, when setting variables in the [configuration file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html), they just fall under the respective `[section]` headers one per line and key values are separated by an equals `=` sign.

So in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` anywhere under `[mysqld]` add:

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```